# Update a DaemonSet without downtime like a deployment

Tags: kubernetes

I want to run an app on any node. It should always have at least one instance per node, but more instances are allowed, primarily during an update to prevent downtime of that pod (and node).

Kubernetes deployment updates usually work by launching a new pod, and as soon as it is available the old one is terminated. That's perfect, but in my case I need a DaemonSet to launch a specific app on all nodes at all times. However, when updating this DaemonSet, Kubernetes kills a pod one by one (i.e. node by node) and **then** launches a new pod, which means that on any given time during an update the pod may not be running on a node.

It seems that DaemonSets are, compared to Deployments, the correct way to do that, but I couldn't find any way to prevent downtime when updating the DaemonSet. Is there any way to do this? I also thought of using Deployments and update a replica amount manuall and antiPodAffinity so only one pod gets deployed per node, but this is kind of hacky.

Comment: This was put on hold (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/51161). So it is not possible.

Comment: An alternative approach is a blue-green deployment. Run both the old and new daemonset, and then once you're satisfied no rollback will occur you can remove the old daemonset. You would double your footprint temporarily, as a downside.

Answer (score 3):

There was a very long set of discussions about adding this feature. You can see them [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/48841) and [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/issues/373)

Long story short, this isn't really possible. You can try and combine `maxUnavailable: 0` and `type: rollingUpdate` in your `updateStrategy` but I don't think that's formally supported.

Example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: my-daemonset
  labels:
    service: my-daemonset
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      service: my-daemonset
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        service: my-daemonset
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: daemonset-update
        image: my-image:latest
```

Comment: It is not allowed to set `maxUnavailable` to 0 as of Today with a DeamonSet.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to perform rolling updates with no downtime using a DeamonSet as of Today! What you need is to have at least 2 nodes running on your cluster and set `maxUnavailable` to 1 in your DaemonSet configuration.

Assuming the previous configuration, when an update is pushed, a first node will start updating. The second will waiting until the first completes. Upon success, the second does the same.

The major drawback is that you need to keep 2 nodes runnings continuously or to take actions to spawn/kill a node before/after an update.

Comment: Cool! I can't try right now, but I will. Can you maybe provide a link of a changelog or where this is documented?

Comment: I have no specific documentation to link other than the one for maxUnavailable. Your use case was similar to mine. I experienced a few things these last days and end up with what is described in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your application can tolerate having more than a single pod per node (which seems to be the case), you could create a second DaemonSet, and delete the original one once you're sure the new DaemonSet is functional.
This process is a bit more involved, but it lets you control when the old pods are deleted.

Note that you'd end up with a DaemonSet under a different name. If that bothers you, you could always repeat the process once more to get back to the original name.

Comment: Not sure if that would work, since I run an http server on top of it so it would have to somehow re-routed?

Comment: @LucaSteeb, This would work for OP, but your needs seem to differ quite a bit from those of the OP, so it might be better to create your own question.

Having said that...
Upgrade means replacing your pod with a newer version. Without having too much experience in this areas, and assuming your workload can't be transferred to another pod dynamically, you may need to introduce some logic to prevent old pods from being assigned new workloads once the new ones are running. This way once all the old pods complete their workloads, you'll be able to delete the DaemonSet.

Comment: I'm the OP :P Either way, I'm not working on this project anymore, so for me personally this is now irrelevant anyway.