# minimise disruption on weave network upgrade on kubernetes

Tags: networking, kubernetes, upgrade, weave, cni

I would like to upgrade my weave network from version 2.5.0 to 2.5.2. I understand that it's "as simple" as updating the weave daemonset.... however, i was wondering if there is a way that this can be done with minimal disruption to running pods on the system.

An simple example in my mind would be to:

- cordon node1
- drain node1 of all pods
- update weave on node1
- uncordon node1

... then rinse and repeat for each k8s node until all done.

Answer (score 0):

Basing on the weave net [documentation](https://www.weave.works/docs/net/latest/kubernetes/kube-addon/)

### [Upgrading the Daemon Sets](https://www.weave.works/docs/net/latest/kubernetes/kube-addon/#-upgrading-the-daemon-sets)

> The DaemonSet definition specifies [Rolling Updates](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-daemon/update-daemon-set/#daemonset-update-strategy), so when you apply a new version Kubernetes will automatically restart the Weave Net pods one by one.
>
> With RollingUpdate update strategy, after you update a DaemonSet template, old DaemonSet pods will be killed, and new DaemonSet pods will be created automatically, in a controlled fashion.

As i could read in another [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57403560/11977760)

> It is possible to perform rolling updates with no downtime using a DeamonSet as of Today! What you need is to have at least 2 nodes running on your cluster and set maxUnavailable to 1 in your DaemonSet configuration.
>
> Assuming the previous configuration, when an update is pushed, a first node will start updating. The second will waiting until the first completes. Upon success, the second does the same.
>
> The major drawback is that you need to keep 2 nodes runnings continuously or to take actions to spawn/kill a node before/after an update.

So i think the best option for you to upgrade your CNI plugin is using DaemonSet with rolling update and set maxUnavailable to 1 in your DaemonSet configuration.